# Prevent jQuery UI Autocomplete from showing similar results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, user-interface

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete to display results avaible on my database. My website is for real estate listings and I'm using it under the field named "Cities" on my search form, so if I have 500 properties listed under the same city, my field will display the name of this city 500 times.

Is there a way I can block this so the same result can be only displayed once?

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'aliicomb_joombd', 'xxxxxxxx', 'aliicomb_joombd');
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);

$query = "SELECT field_63 FROM jbd_joomd_type15 WHERE field_63 LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY field_63 ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['field_63'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
?>
```

And my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#field_63').autocomplete(
    {
        source: "city.php",
        minLength: 3
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: a tip. see [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (not directly related to your problem though.)

Answer (score 3):

you can fetch distinct values from DB using DISTINCT keyword in your query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT field_63 FROM jbd_joomd_type15 WHERE field_63 LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY field_63 ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan Hušnjak suggests you could try either

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT field_63 FROM jbd_joomd_type15 WHERE field_63 LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY field_63 ASC";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 1 field_63 FROM jbd_joomd_type15 WHERE field_63 LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY field_63 ASC";
```

to return just 1 result from the DB

be aware that DISTINCT can still return more than one result if there are multiple rows where field_63 is like $text